# CRM 2011: Find current grid in ribbon JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon, subgrid

This one is driving me mad....

I have several subgrids in a form, all of the same entity and filtered to different fields. A button in the grid's ribbon calls a function that needs to know the exact grid "instance" to make a decision - and this is where I am completely lost.

In my ribbon definition, I pass the CrmParameter SelectedControl to the called function. This is supposed to be the active grid - and it apparently is, in a way at least.

What I would like to do in my JavaScript code is get one of my grids via its name and then compare it to the object that's passed into my function - only that this is some completely different object, and you can do next to nothing with it.
You can't get its name, ID, label whatever; of all the methods listed for controls in the SDK, only four work: getVisible(), setVisible(), setFocus() and refresh(). These are not very useful for what I need to do.

A colleague then told me to try Xrm.Page.ui.getCurrentControl() - but that shows the exact same behavior, although funnily the two objects aren't even equal.

I found something vague through Google that used the .control property of a control retrieved via .getControl(), so I compared the one obtained via .getCurrentControl() to that - and they matched. Unfortunately, the "current control" matches the .control properties of *all* subgrids.

Some code to make it clearer what is what:

```
function ribbonAction(param) // param is the SelectedControl parameter
{
    var current = Xrm.Page.ui.getCurrentControl();
    var grid1 = Xrm.Page.getControl("grid1");
    var grid2 = Xrm.Page.getControl("grid2");

    alert(param == current);            // false
    alert(param == grid1);              // false
    alert(param == grid1.control);      // false
    alert(current == grid1);            // false
    alert(current == grid1.control);    // true
    alert(current == grid2.control);    // true

    alert(current.getName());           // throws an error
    alert(param.getName());             // throws an error

    current.refresh();                  // refreshes the correct grid
    param.refresh();                    // refreshes the correct grid
}
```

The comments tell what happens when the ribbon button is clicked while grid1 is active.

I would be very grateful for any hints on how to really identify the active subgrid control in that situation.

Comment: Is that normal that you set grid2 with a control called "grid1"? That would explain what it also returns true for the 6th expression.

Comment: No, that just came from copying that line; this is only example code to sum up all my observations, my real controls have distinct names not as easily mixed up. Thank you for pointing out that typo.

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me mad too! Here is how I cracked it:

Specify a global variable in a JavaScript library for the entity form in which your sub grids reside.

```
var SelectedSubGrid;
```

In the same library add a function called TagGrid as follows....

```
function TagGrid(SubGridName)
{
            if(document.getElementById(SubGridName + "_d") != null)
            {
                        document.getElementById(SubGridName + "_d").onclick = function () { SelectedSubGrid = SubGridName };
            }
}
```

Then add a second function called GetCurrentGrid as follows....

```
function GetCurrentGrid()
{
            // add code here to check current grid and execute differently as required...
            alert('Current Grid is ' + SelectedSubGrid);          
}
```

Include a call to the TagGrid function for each subgrid of the same entity type. In my example below I have two sub grids of custom entity type 'Business Pitch Event', one grid named 'DocumentationEvents' and the other 'BusinessPitchEventEvents'.

```
function OnLoad()
{
            TagGrid("DocumentationEvents");
            TagGrid("BusinessPitchEventEvents");
}
```

Then on your sub grid ribbon button, call the GetCurrentGrid function!